# DokuWiki with SVN: how and what should be under source control

Tags: dokuwiki

I want to store my documentation under SVN source control.

In DokuWiki settings there is

```
Directory for saving data          '.../apps/dokuwiki/data'
```

DokuWiki stores all data inside text files under **'.../apps/dokuwiki/data'** folder. There are many stuffs there including indexes caches etc. It seems that I only need the **'pages'** folder.

How can I move the **'pages'** folder inside my SVN folders and configure the DocuWiki to use pages from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conf['datadir']` can be used in `conf/local.php` to set the page directory independently from the rest of the directories in `data`. You probably want to use `$conf['mediadir]` for uploaded images and files as well and maybe `$conf['metadir']` for saving page metadata.

Comment: Thanks, do I need metadata in SVN? In other words, can metadata be regenerated by DokuWiki?

Comment: Should not it be `$conf['datadir']` instead of `$conf['pagedir']`? [DokuWiki help](http://www.dokuwiki.org/config:savedir)

Comment: Yes, it's datadir. Not all metadata can be recreated by DokuWiki.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I set mine to:

```
$conf['datadir'] = './my-data/pages/';
$conf['mediadir'] = './my-data/media/';
$conf['metadir'] = './my-data/meta/';
```

N.B. Be sure to use `'datadir'` (not `'pagedir'`) as noted in the comments to the earlier answer.

You may also want to configure your attic:

```
$conf['olddir'] = './my-data/attic/';
```

This makes management under svn more complicated, as you have to add attic files all the time, but it preserves change history across developers. This depends a little more on your installation though; if you [regularly clean your attic](http://www.dokuwiki.org/tips%3amaintenance) you wouldn't want to do this.