# Cache and Meta files in Dokuwiki

Tags: dokuwiki

I have dokuwiki in a version control system so every file is tracked. I am therefore trying to limit the number of not needed files created. Every change I make I see files in data/attic and data/meta being created. Can I safely add these to .gitignore?

I understand attic stores snapshots which I don't need due to version control and meta stores indexes which I can re-generate.

My concern is will data/meta ever store files that are critical for the functioning of dokuwkiki?

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been asked before here on Stackoverflow as well as in the DokuWiki user forum. Here are just two examples I found with a quick search:

- [DokuWiki with SVN: how and what should be under source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696181/dokuwiki-with-svn-how-and-what-should-be-under-source-control/)
- https://forum.dokuwiki.org/thread/13110

To answer your question, yes `data/meta` will contain data that you can not recreate from page info. For example who created a page in the first place. Plugins also may store important data there.